# How to use a query with parameterin Power BI?

Tags: parameters, powerbi, directquery

I have  a query that get the number of days from the user and display the result, like the following:

```
declare number_of_days = 10
select *
from myTable
where getdate() - opendate > number_of_days
```

I use direct query mode in Power BI and want to get the value for the parameter from the user and then show the result to them.

How can I use a query with parameter in Power BI direct query mode?

Answer (score 0):

Use [Dynamic M query parameters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-dynamic-m-query-parameters) to re-generate a SQL query which you use with a [Native Query](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-query/native-query-folding.)